# Recover files formatted / broken partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, data-recovery

I recently got my hard disk broke (not physically broke) and that I tried to do data recovery.  I've tried Easeus and GetBackData tool already, it works great and I can recover files, however there is just one issue that the PST file I have there in the hard disk, which is about 6GB as  far as I remember, is not 0 bytes.

Is there a way to recover this file at all? If yes, then what tools are needed?

Comment: It got overwritten and/or is corrupted beyond recovery. Pull it from backup.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't get it from backup, I recommend SpinRite at GRC.com for $89 USD.   Written by Security Now's Steve Gibson, SpinRite can be used on any operating system and any file system. This means it can run on drives formatted with Windows XP's/Vista's/Windows 7's NTFS and all other older FAT formats (in addition to all Linux, Novell, and all other file systems.)

Follow the instructions download the ISO and create a live CD (or other bootable media), including its own bootable FreeDOS operating system. Run Spinrite at level 2 first and check the PST file. If that doesn't work run at level 5. There is a step-by-step video at https://www.grc.com/sr/whatitdoes.htm

Spinrite is a must have" tools for the computer pro or serious hobbyist.  It can be used to pre-qualify and certify unformatted hard drives before their first use. Drives on non-PC platforms, such as Apple Macintosh or TiVo, may be temporarily relocated to a PC motherboard for data recovery, maintenance and repair by SpinRite. SpinRite provides complete interaction with IDE-interface PATA (parallel ATA) and SATA (Serial ATA) drives, and it can also be used with any other type of drive — SCSI, USB, 1394/Firewire — that can be made visible to DOS through the addition of controller BIOS or add-on DOS drivers.

After you are done, tend to your backup process.